# Google Drive SDK login as another user with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api

I used Google authentication in my website to simplify user accounts implementation.

When a user logs out, I clear the session variable and reset the authenticated Google API Client object.

The problem is, when I want to log in as another user, I am immediately and automatically logged in to my previous Google account.

How do I handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if that can be controlled without logging out of your Google account. By logging in through your Google account I believe you are subsequently logging into your Google account not only your website. Stack-overflow itself works in the exact same way.

Comment: do you have any suggestions that can help me get around this problem?

Comment: I think it is out of your control ultimately, I have not used the Google login but have implemented the twitter OAuth login on previous projects and it behaves in the same way. Google/Twitter are essentially capitalising on the opportunity to sign that user into their services at the same time as providing you the authentication mechanism.

Comment: i believe there is an option in twitter to force the user to enter his/her credentials. but thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login, specifically the 'prompt' parameter. You could add prompt=select_account to force account selection.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't have to add the prompt parameter outside testing. It's not a very common pattern for users to switch accounts like that -- login, logout, log in with another. More likely:

1. They just have one account.
2. They have multiple accounts are are logged in simultaneously.
3. They have multiple accounts and use different browser profiles to isolate them

For 1 & 3, automatic login is fine. For 2, they should be prompted to select the account by default and you shouldn't have to do anything special.

Comment: thanks for the info! do you know how i can do it with the ruby google drive sdk?

Comment: You can pass it in via the options to authorization_url(). See https://github.com/google/signet/blob/master/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb